# How to delete the item from the list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im creating an app using ionic and angularjs. In the app developing I have used swipe option from the ionic to delete the specific coupon from the main-list. The problem I problem face here is, Im only able to delete the description of the selected coupon, but not able to delete/remove the coupon from the main-list. Also I have use `$rootScope` where I have declared my `json array`. I have declare a `$scope.item` into which the selected coupon and its details are being pushed, in-order to display the description of each selected coupons. I'm going wrong somewhere in the code please help me to get it right. Thank you.

HTML:

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-click="select_item(coupons)" ng-repeat="coupons in couponList" ng-model="coupons.selected">
            {{coupons.CouponTitle}} <br>
            <ion-option-button ng-click="editCoupons(coupons)">Edit</ion-option-button>
            <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="deleteSelected(coupons)">Delete</ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <hr>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            Coupon offer: {{item.data.description}}<br> Valid From: {{item.data.Fromldate}}
            <br> Valid Till: {{item.data.Todate}} </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.items = [];
      $rootScope.couponList = [{ CouponTitle: "Purchase worth $100", data: {description: "$50 off", Fromldate: "2016-09-09", Todate: "2016-09-18"}},
      {CouponTitle: "Purchase worth $300",  data:{description: "$75 off", Fromldate: "2016-11-09", Todate: "2016-10-19"}},
      { CouponTitle: "Purchase worth $500",data:{description: "$95 off", Fromldate: "2016-09-10", Todate: "2016-09-30"}}];

      $scope.select_item = function (key) {
        $scope.items.push(key);

      }

 $scope.deleteSelected = function () {
           $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in one answer you can use the `$index` mechanism to remove an object from an array.

You have to delete both from `items array` and `rootscope array`

**View:**

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="deleteSelected($index,coupons)">Delete</ion-option-button>
```

**Controller:**

```
 $scope.deleteSelected = function (index,coupons) {
     $rootScope.couponList.splice(index,1);

     var to_delete = $scope.items.find(find_data)

     function find_data(items) { 
        return items.CouponTitle === coupons.CouponTitle;
     }

     var index = $scope.items.indexOf(to_delete);

     $scope.items.splice(index,1)


 }
```

[HEre is a partial implemented fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3585/)

You should delete both the items array and also, `couponList` to remove in `ng-repeat`

Comment: @jazzoria, please check my answer.

Comment: Can you explain me how to use `ng-repeat` for this. Please

Comment: it is the same as you taken, check the fiddle link,
`<ion-item ng-click="select_item(coupons)" ng-repeat="coupons in couponList" ng-model="coupons.selected">`

Comment: and I also tried the controller you have defined here. I was only able to delete the coupons from list but not the displayed details i.e anyone of the splice action is working but not both together.

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: I understood your issue, updating the answer.

Comment: you save my day.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

pass index inside deleteSelected as a parameter, and delete from array directly.

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="deleteSelected($index)">Delete</ion-option-button>
```

**But for $index you will have to use track by $index mechanism of ng-repeat.**

Let me know if you want more clerification.

Comment: I used $index but was able to delete only the description but not the coupon from main list. @Jigar7521